# LinkedHashMap getting sorted by keys

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` that reverses the order of insertion when I get values out of it. Any ideas why?

```
private final Map<Long, DD> cachedPlansById=new LinkedHashMap<Long, DD>();
cachedPlansById.put(dd.getId(), dd);
```

Values out of dao, when inserted into `LinkesHashMap` go in this order->

```
dao Spring  6
dao Fall  5
dao Annual  4
dao Spring 2010 3
dao Fall 2009 2
dao Annual 2010-2011 1
```

But when I retrieve them out of `LinkedHashMap`, they're reordered like this->

```
valu Annual 2010-2011 1
valu Fall 2009 2
valu Spring 2010 3
valu Annual  4
valu Fall  5
valu Spring  6
```

I use this for loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<Long, PaymentPlan> m:cachedPlansById.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("valu "+m.getValue().getName()+" "+m.getValue().getId());
}
```

Comment: Give us a reproducible example.

Comment: So the question is why is LinkedHashMap an instanceof HashMap and not LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please provide us the piece of code where your values are inserted ?

Because as you can veritfy with this little example, the `LinkedHashMap` iterator is following the insertion order.

```
    Map<Long, String> cachedPlansById = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
    cachedPlansById.put(6L, "Spring");
    cachedPlansById.put(5L, "Fall");
    for (Map.Entry<Long, String> m : cachedPlansById.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.getValue() + " " + m.getKey());
    }
```

Result is:

```
Spring 6
Fall 5
```

Just for information, [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) has also a constructor where it follows the access order instead of the insertion order.

> A special constructor is provided to create a linked hash map whose
>   order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last
>   accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently
>   (access-order). This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU
>   caches. Invoking the put or get method results in an access to the
>   corresponding entry (assuming it exists after the invocation
>   completes). The putAll method generates one entry access for each
>   mapping in the specified map, in the order that key-value mappings are
>   provided by the specified map's entry set iterator. No other methods
>   generate entry accesses. In particular, operations on collection-views
>   do not affect the order of iteration of the backing map.

Comment: I guess I'm calling the access order constructor then because my output is the reverse of insertion order. I need to make sure to call the insertion order constructor I guess. Thanks. And I checked my code for putting entries in map, I'm printing keys and values before putting, so I know they're in right order.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. To call the access order constructor you would have called `Map<Long, String> cachedPlansById = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>(5, 5f, true);` Can you share the part where you insert the values ?

Comment: I figured the problem I think. I did an instanceof HashMap, it returned true, but when I do instanceof LinkedHashMap, it returns false. Not sure why its instantiating it as a HashMap. And I insert the values in that put statement.